# Change the cursor when hovering between 2 Listview columns

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, cursor

Is there a way to change the cursor to default, when hovering between 2 Listview columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your question clear. ListView doesn't provide mouse hover event for Column Header. If you try to move the mouse on the column header then you will not get any event where you can determine that mouse is hovering. If you are talking about the client area of ListView Control then you can do like this.

```
private void listView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (r.Contains(e.Location))
        return;
    int columnIndex = getColumnIndex(e.Location);
    if (columnIndex == 3)
        listView1.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    else
        listView1.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
Rectangle r = Rectangle.Empty;
private int getColumnIndex(Point p)
{
    r = Rectangle.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        r = new Rectangle(r.X + r.Width, 0, listView1.Columns[i].Width, listView1.Height);
        if (r.Contains(p))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: But can you not change the cursor All the time when moving inside the listview for example? I tried something like that, but did not got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy, but it is possible.

The basic strategy is to listen for the `WM_SETCURSOR` on the ListView's header control, and inside the handler for that message, check if the mouse is over the divider you want, then either cancel the message (leaves cursor as default) or allow it to proceed (changes the cursor).

[ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.com) does exactly this.